# Convert SQL query to Android Azure Mobile Service query - DISTINCT Statement

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-mobile-services

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * messages FROM messages WHERE sender_id = 1
```

Into Azure Mobile Service

```
messagesTable.where().field("sender_id").eq(1).execute().get();
```

The problem is selecting DISTINCT columns. This is on android.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use Android client SDK for Azure Mobile Apps to write the code for querying the `DISTINCT` column, but there is not any method directly support it via [`Query`](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/table/query/Query.html) interface on Android client SDK.

The only way is [calling a custom API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#a-namecustom-apiahow-to-call-a-custom-api) from android client to execute custom SQL statements at the backend server, please refer to the subsection `How to: Execute custom SQL statements` of the document section [`Custom APIs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#a-namecustomapia-custom-apis) and the [`data/execute`](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_data_execute.html) method for Node.js backend.